# How to decompile the UWP ComboBox code?

Tags: c#, uwp, decompiling

I located the ComboBox class in the UniversalApiContract class, but the declarations in it are **extern**. Where can I find the real implementation of these?

Comment: That class is likely implemented in C++ in the OS. And you can't really decompile compiled C++ code. Why do you want to decompile it?

Comment: I just wanted to see how certain methods in it are implemented.